# Vertically centering div caption over responsive image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to vertically center an absolutely positioned caption over an image that has a flexible height (max-width: 100%;) and having trouble. I know I need to use JS to detect the height of the div and adjust the top positioning of the caption div, but I'm having trouble.

http://jsfiddle.net/A69Xr/

```
    <div id="nav">navigation</div>
<div id="slider">
    <img src="http://codeword.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/aspen_colorado.jpg">
    <div class="caption">
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the width and height of the caption you could accomplish it in CSS:

Say the caption was 400px wide and 90px tall

```
#slider {
    position:relative;
}

.caption {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-200px;
    margin-top:-45px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:400px;
    height:90px;
}
```

This would push it to the center 50%. Then you offset half the width and half the height with negative margins. And that will center it for you.

Comment: This might work, as long as I could vertically center the content instead of .caption if it happens to run smaller than the height that I've set. I tried using table, table-cell, and vertical-align to achieve this but had no luck. [http://jsfiddle.net/A69Xr/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/A69Xr/5/).

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to fix it using table, table-cell, and vertical-align and vertically center whatever is within .caption regardless of whether or not it fills the entire height set. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using jQuery:

1) Get the height of `img` tag.
2) Set the top of caption class as half the height of image.

```
var imgHeight = $('img').height();
$('.caption').css({'top': imgHeight/2});
```

Comment: Thanks! Any reason why it's slightly off center here? Also, I realize that it only shows based on resize, but how do I get it to show onload as well? Thanks again for your help.

[http://jsfiddle.net/A69Xr/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/A69Xr/4/)